# How to enable tls vers. 1.2 in haproxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy, tls1.2

I have haproxy doing ssl termination. I have disabled sslv3.

The ssl testers says that I only have tls 1.0 enabled. How can I  enable tls version 1.2 in haproxy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

We can specify these informations in default:

1. ssl-default-server-options force-tlsv12
   It will apply for all server commands in haproxy config
2. ssl-default-bind-options force-tlsv12
   It will apply for all bind command in haproxy config.

Comment: what is differents between `...-server-options` and `...-bind-options` option ?

Comment: @Nullpointer bind options dictate connection behaviors with clients; server options dictate connection behaviors with backend servers.

Comment: A dumb question probably, but I've got mode as tcp, so in that case, how could I force tlsv12 ?

Comment: Also, adding the above properties in default throw the error of unknown properties. I'm using v1.5.18 on a Centos 7 machine

Comment: Adding the options under "global" instead of "defaults" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check version of openssl. TLS 1.2 is in version 1.0.x. Older (for example 0.9.8 in Debian Squeeze) supports only TLS 1.0.